# Adobe Air - Unrestricted access warning

Tags: air, installation

Is there a way to restrict the access of an Adobe Air application so that the *unresticted access* message doesnt show up in the [install dialog](http://jadedsecurity.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Screen-shot-2011-06-25-at-1.22.03-PM.jpg)?

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can get your application [signed](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/signing-air-applications.html). This will prevent that message from appearing, even though there has been no change to the access the application has…